# How to convert datatable to corresponding "named" and "typed" IEnumerable for Intellisense

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, reflection, lambda

Possibly a dup but I tried googling and searching here before posting.

Assume a 2 column table with columns

Age (int) and EmpName (string)

A datatable can be converted to IEnumerable by a simple dbTable.AsEnumerable()

Now to perform any Linq you must know the column names since intellisense will not pick it up due the fact that AsEnumerable has returned a bunch of datarows that you can enumerate. I have used a small 2 col table but for tables with many columns it is a pain.
So most of the time we try something like

```
var results = from p in dbTable.AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
               name = p.Field<string>("name"),
               age = p.Field<int>("age")
            };
```

Now finally when we type results and press . (dot) intellisense will show name and age in the drop down. 
Question: Using reflection to query for column names and column types how can I do something like

```
var results = YourMagicRoutine(dbTable);
//You can use lambda etc instead of method call in above line
```

results should now intellisense and show correct column names

thank you

Comment: Bypass all the mess by using a custom class `IEnumerable<Employee>` rather than using a datatable.

Comment: There are times when data is already in a datable (dataset with data from say sql server and dataset populated with multiple tables or resultsets. But agree whenever possible I avoid datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflection in order to construct a type at **runtime**; however, it will be of no use at **design-time**, where intellisense actually happens!

---

However, you could use the magic of an O/R-mapper. O/R-mappers map database tables to classes. Instead of working with DataSets, Tables, Rows and TableAdapters, you work with domain objects. With an O/R-mapper you would work like this

```
List<Person> people = dbContext.Query<Person>()
    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A"))
    .OrderBy(p => p.Age)
    .ToList();
```

There are a lot of O/R-mappers around. Therefore I don't refer to a specific one here.

Comment: Oops. Totally forgot this reflection thingy works only at runtime. I have played with Dapper before. I will revisit O/R mappers. thx

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You need to know the information about the columns at compile time to get intellisense.  You can go, at runtime, and create a magic object that looks into the columns of the datatable and creates properties, but then *that* object won't have any intellisense.

As mentioned in comments, if you store the data in a class specific to that type rather than through a datatable you won't have this issue.  If not, you'll need to convert each row into some other type (whether anonymous or not) manually to get intellisense out of it.